# Klling Thread with telepot

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, python-multithreading, python-telegram-bot

I'm tring to use on my main thread another thread.
The main one is the telegram bot api and the second one is opencv file.
I tryed all-ready multiprocessing and subprocess but its wont work because of the threading library that the bot runs on.
after all i maneged to establish the "sub-thread" but it wont exit the "sub-thread".It works only once and thats it.
I didnt found any useful information for how you can exit the "sub-thread" with **other** command from the telegram bot,
like:

```
elif telegramText == '/exit_thread':
        if my_thread.isalive():
           my_thead.exit()/my_thread.end()
           bot.sendMessage(chat_id, str("the thread isnt working, re-enter the /enb command for the new open cv thread"))
```

creats the thread as number 1:

```
elif telegramText == '/enb':
        numbers = [1]
        for number in numbers:
            my_thread = Thread(target=doubler, args=(number, ))
            my_thread.start()
```

deffines what the thread need to do:

```
def doubler(number):
if number==1:
    #print(threading.currentThread().getName() + '\n')
    bot.sendMessage(chat_id, str("Its on, Youre safe!"))
    if full_body_detec.body_detec():
        bot.sendMessage(chat_id, str("I saw some-one!! see it your self"))
        bot.sendPhoto(chat_id, photo=open('intruder.jpg', 'rb'))
        bot.sendVideo(chat_id = chat_id,video = open('output2.mp4',mode ='rb'))
```

I really am stuck guys would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Use [threading.Thread.join](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.join) method `my_thread.join()`, but not `.exit()` or `.end()`

P.S. watch out of typos I see 2 variables that you use: my_thead and my_th**r**ead